# .htaccess, rewrite middle directory to not exist in url, not redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

So I've been spending too much time on this. I have a url.

```
http://nootropicsexpert.com/community-forum/forum/cutting-edge-research/
```

I want to **remove "forum/"** so it looks like:

```
http://nootropicsexpert.com/community-forum/cutting-edge-research/
```

**But I don't want the location to change, i just want to change the appearance of the url.**

I've tried many things, and seems I just end up with 404 pages.

**How can I just change just the appearance of this url? with htaccess?** 
*Mind you the child "cutting-edge-research/" is dynamic. The rest of the url is always the same.*

Comment: @anubhava the url right after i said "I want to remove "forum/" so it looks like:" yes, its a wordpress website, so there is an htaccess file the wordpress installation root

Comment: For WP you will need to use WP rewrite API not .htaccess